# SQL query to datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I had done till one last part. Unsure how or what should I do to add into code.

```
public String DisplaySheetList()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    GridView gv = new GridView();

    string sqlStatement1 = "SELECT cs.SheetId AS sheet_id, ltm.LocationType AS location_type, cs.PalletNo AS palletNo, cs.period AS period,cs.syncDate AS syncDate,cs.syncStatus AS syncStatus "
                + "FROM CountSheet cs JOIN LocationTypeMaster ltm ON ltm.LocationId = cs.LocationId " +
                " ORDER BY 1 DESC";
    SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement1, conn); 
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd1);
    sqlDa1.Fill(dt);

     //What should i put here

     gv.DataBind();
}
```

I created the table and the view, got the query and fill it in to the table (if I am not wrong). Is it completed or is thing else I should do to ensure it is in the gridview so I can display them out.

Any help will be good, thank you guys

Comment: Did you run it and see?

Comment: can you add some more tags including the .net framework you are using and the database

Comment: Use `gv.DataSource = dt` to assign gridview data source when `DataTable` is already filled from `DataAdapter` by `sqlDa1.Fill(dt)`.

Comment: A **HIGHLY RECOMMENDED SUGGESTION**, start using parameterized SQL, to prevent SQL Injection. Maybe it's not an important aspect as you seem starting to learn filling dg from db. But you should start with this approach

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.
@o_O yes i am aware, thank you for the suggestion. i will look up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put :

`gv.DataSource=dt;`

in place of **What should i put here** to bind datatable data to gridview

Answer (score 1):

So after you fill the result in your data table

Make `dt` the gridview datasource.

```
//put it in the gridview datasource.    
gv.DataSource = dt;
```

You can refer to this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) for setting gridview datasource

To complete your code:

```
public String DisplaySheetList()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    GridView gv = new GridView();

    string sqlStatement1 = "SELECT cs.SheetId AS sheet_id, ltm.LocationType AS location_type, cs.PalletNo AS palletNo, cs.period AS period,cs.syncDate AS syncDate,cs.syncStatus AS syncStatus "
                + "FROM CountSheet cs JOIN LocationTypeMaster ltm ON ltm.LocationId = cs.LocationId " +
                " ORDER BY 1 DESC";
    SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement1, conn); 
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd1);
    sqlDa1.Fill(dt);

    //put it in the gridview datasource.    
    gv.DataSource = dt;

    gv.DataBind();
}
```